# QGIS 3 doesn't propertly read umlaut from shapefile encoded in UTF-8

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, import, encoding, utf-8

I'm using shapefiles with encoding UTF-8 that were used in ArcGIS before. The German umlaut  ( ¨ )  are shown as a question mark. In `Layer Properties -> Source -> Settings` the encoding is set to UTF-8. Do I have to make additional settings so that I can see German umlaut?

Comment: Have you opened the *.cpg file in a text editor to make sure the encoding is utf-8?

Comment: That they show as question marks indicates that they were set to the wrong encoding when saving the file. Otherwise an `ü` would be shown as `Ã¼`. So the information is lost completely. You need access to the original source to fix this: Before saving the data to shapefile, make sure the correct encoding is chosen.

Comment: have you tried latin encoding? Sometimes switching helpes.

Comment: MRXsqaured what do you mean by original source?

Comment: How can I find the *.cpg file?

Comment: after saving the shapefiles with encoding UTF-8 I have a cpg-file, it contains the encoding UTF-8 but the question marks are still there

Comment: after saving a shapefile to UTF-8 there is now 1/2 for german umlaut('') no idea what I have to do now to get rid of this

Comment: Prepare a small dataset for testing and share it.

Comment: Make sure you set the encoding when importing the file. Changing it once it's in QGIS will not help.

Comment: Sorry can't share the files

Comment: is this problem in the data and the column names? or just in the column names?

Comment: Maybe this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301383/converting-excel-into-shapefile-keeping-encoding-and-data-type can also help you

Answer (score 3):

If ü is being shown as Ã¼ you actually have Windows 1252 encoding not UTF-8. They overlap for some chars but not all. See https://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=65001&decoding=1252 for a table of values

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case it helped switch to Windows-1250.